# Android compile error using buildozer

Tags: android, python, macos, kivy

I am trying to compile an .apk ([this one](https://github.com/tshirtman/kivy_service_osc)) using buildozer. But I keep getting the command failed message below. I've tried using a different python path, reinstalling buildozer, using different buildozer paths, compiling from Mac HD, compiling with sudo, a different cython version. None work.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "build.py", line 497, in 
>       make_package(args)
>     File "build.py", line 351, in make_package
>       subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
>       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
>   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1
>
> Command failed: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python build.py --name 'My Application' --version 1.2.0 --package org.test.myapp --private /Users/user/Documents/Py/kvapk/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --permission INTERNET --permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE --orientation portrait debug

I'm on OSX Mavericks using python 2.7.5, kivy 1.8.0, cython 0.19 and buildozer 0.17

Here is the total output: https://gist.github.com/feynman21/29d2f02c387112f2900b

Comment: Edit your `buildozer.spec` and set `log_level = 2`, then post the output.

Comment: @feynman21 I'm curious, are you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an issue with buildozer failing to install the Android build-tools. Hopefully this will be fixed soon. Until then, you can work around this by manually installing build-tools (https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/146#issuecomment-57061269):

1. Run `~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools/android` to launch the Android SDK Manager. (If you have a different SDK version, replace `android-sdk-21` with the appropriate folder)
2. Click the `Deselect All` link at the bottom of the window, and check the box next to "Android SDK Build-tools -- 20". (Note: the exact version doesn't matter, just pick the newest version available.)  [image: screenshot from 2014-09-27 13 17 13]
3. Click the `Install 1 package...` button.
4. Click `Accept License` and then click the `Install` button. [image: screenshot from 2014-09-27 13 19 19]
5. Close the SDK Manager and resume working with buildozer.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this in a system that doesn't have X , but text only?

Comment: 2014 is over. 2015 almost over. Still no answer - I'm running this in a Vagrant and can't do this (?) - Will try to start X server on OSX and export display and pray.

Comment: for me issue was with version in buildozer.spec

version = 0.20151220.1 #not working version = 0.1 working so have a look at yours also