# error compiling kivy project with buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to compile my kivy project for android with buildozer and get the following error:

> cp: cannot stat `build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_ctypes*.so': No such
>   file  or directory

I tried it on mac and on linux, got the same error, used last version of buildozer (installed it today with pip).

Comment: Please read http://buildozer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277154/android-compile-error-using-buildozer

Comment: https://github.com/sabotage-linux/sabotage/issues/15

Comment: tried everything from answers above... did not help... :(

Comment: I think this may be a bug arising from a recent PR merge into python-for-android. I've raised the issue and we'll try to work out what is the problem.

Comment: I have the same error, using the latest buildozer from git, Ubuntu 16.04 and python 3.5.2, when trying to follow the installation instructions at http://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html.

Comment: @inclement, do you mind pointing me toward any kivy github issue tracking this?

Comment: I think the issue I was referring to there is now resolved, and I don't have a particular github issue for this problem in mind. If you can reproduce the issue, it would be great if you could open a github issue with the full build log.