# Kivy: building android app with buildozer

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to Kivy, I encountered a problem when trying to build the apk with Buildozer. I got error

"BUILD FAILED
/home/handsome/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools/ant/build.xml:399: SDK Platform Tools component is missing. Please install it with the SDK Manager (tools/android)"

when I executed the build command. I have installed a lot package and still got the same error. Please help! Million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a current bug in buildozer, since a recent SDK update.

Kived has some great instructions to work around it at [Android compile error using buildozer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277154/android-compile-error-using-buildozer/26308042#26308042) (this might have been for a previous, similar bug but you can still install just the newest version).